# How do I propagate SQS calls with OpenTelemetry auto-instrumentation

Tags: java, open-telemetry, aws-xray

I've done the necessary sidecar setup in CloudFormation for the collector and added the following to my docker file for my Java applications deployed in AWS ECS (obviously replacing myservice with relevant name):

```
ENV OTEL_SERVICE_NAME="MyService"
ENV OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT="http://localhost:4317"
ENV OTEL_PROPAGATORS="tracecontext,baggage,xray"

CMD java -XX:+UseContainerSupport -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80.0 -javaagent:aws-opentelemetry-agent.jar -jar myservice-1.0.jar
```

Traces for calls to synchronous endpoints work fantastically but traces do not seem to be propagated across SQS calls.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hello - this may be an issue with the AWS SDK instrumentation. The instrumentation should pass in trace context as an [SQS system message attribute](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-metadata.html#sqs-message-system-attributes) for it to be recognized downstream. Please open an issue here to describe this bug: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/

Comment: https://github.com/aws-observability/aws-otel-java-instrumentation/issues/244. It is already a message attribute. Basically this is a general with SQS. The instrumentation should automatically extracts the SQS trace context into a span per message received

Answer (score 1):

With a current state of opentelemetry library (1.31.0) from my (somewhat limited) understanding, the attributes are correctly propagated to SQS queue when `otel.instrumentation.aws-sdk.experimental-use-propagator-for-messaging` property is specified (or an `OTEL_INSTRUMENTATION_AWS_SDK_EXPERIMENTAL_USE_PROPAGATOR_FOR_MESSAGING` env variable).

However, when they are read from the SQS message attributes on the receiving side, a context with trace values is created and immediately closed without wrapping the actual message handling (see [code on GitHub](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/blob/v1.31.0/instrumentation/aws-sdk/aws-sdk-2.2/library/src/main/java/io/opentelemetry/instrumentation/awssdk/v2_2/SqsImpl.java#L88)):

```java
  private static void createConsumerSpan(
      Message message,
      SdkHttpResponse httpResponse,
      ExecutionAttributes executionAttributes,
      TracingExecutionInterceptor config) {

    io.opentelemetry.context.Context parentContext = io.opentelemetry.context.Context.root();

    TextMapPropagator messagingPropagator = config.getMessagingPropagator();
    if (messagingPropagator != null) {
      parentContext =
          SqsParentContext.ofMessageAttributes(message.messageAttributes(), messagingPropagator);
    }

    if (config.shouldUseXrayPropagator()
        && parentContext == io.opentelemetry.context.Context.root()) {
      parentContext = SqsParentContext.ofSystemAttributes(message.attributesAsStrings());
    }

    Instrumenter<ExecutionAttributes, SdkHttpResponse> consumerInstrumenter =
        config.getConsumerInstrumenter();
    if (consumerInstrumenter.shouldStart(parentContext, executionAttributes)) {
      io.opentelemetry.context.Context context =
          consumerInstrumenter.start(parentContext, executionAttributes);

      // TODO: Even if we keep HTTP attributes (see afterMarshalling), does it make sense here
      //  per-message?
      // TODO: Should we really create root spans if we can't extract anything, or should we attach
      //  to the current context?
      consumerInstrumenter.end(context, executionAttributes, httpResponse, null);
    }
  }
```

As a far as I see, that's done like this because AWS SQS SDK pulls messages in batches (even if you set it to a batch size of 1 it will still be a list).
You would need to setup manual span creation from remote parent in a place of message handling. Something like this should work (example written in kotlin, should be similar for java):

```kotlin
import software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.Message

    val tracer: Tracer

    fun handle(
        message: Message,
        block: (Message) -> Unit,
    ) {
        val span = createSpan(message)
        try {
            span.makeCurrent().use { block(message) }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            span.recordException(e)
            throw e
        } finally {
            span.end()
        }
    }

   fun createSpan(message: Message): Span {
        // Example uses b3multi headers, change to what is used in your case
        val traceId = message.messageAttributes()["X-B3-TraceId"]?.stringValue()
        val spanId = message.messageAttributes()["X-B3-SpanId"]?.stringValue()
        val isSampled = message.messageAttributes()["X-B3-Sampled"]
            ?.stringValue()
            ?.let { it == "true" || it == "1" }
            ?: false
        val traceFlags = if (isSampled) TraceFlags.getSampled() else TraceFlags.getDefault()
        return if (traceId != null && spanId != null) {
            tracer.spanBuilder("span-name")
                .setParent(
                    Context.current().with(
                        Span.wrap(
                            SpanContext.createFromRemoteParent(
                                traceId,
                                spanId,
                                traceFlags,
                                TraceState.getDefault(),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ).startSpan()
        } else {
            Span.current()
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** it seems like propagation with SqsTemplate (in case of spring) doesn't work reliably, because for the first request a queue url is fetched and then in an async manner the actual send request is done.

Comment: I got the same problem, the code 
`
    Span.wrap(
                                SpanContext.createFromRemoteParent(
                                    traceId,
                                    spanId,
                                    traceFlags,
                                    TraceState.getDefault(),
                                ),
                        ),
`
is not correct as the type is different. How can create remote context ?

Comment: Hey @Yang, I've fixed a problem with `isSampled` in the example.